# What kind of spider is this? I have never seen one like this before

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

This was on my butterfly bush yesterday with a moth by the neck.  I have never seen one like this before.  Just wondering what the name is.  This is in southern Illinois.

Comment: Excellent picture!  Someone will know this -- might take a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

On [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/62035-Misumenoides-formosipes) I found a very similar picture, of a White-Banded Crab Spider.  It is found in your area.  It's a possibility.